# Can I click on the link within the :target element

Tags: css, focus, target

So I have the code below.

```
<nav>
<div class="clicker" tabindex="1">menu</div>
<div class="hiddendiv">  <a href="/register/register">Register</a>
<a href="/account/login">Login</a></div>
</nav>
```

with the following css

```
nav{    margin-top: -70px;
} .clicker { font-size: 4em; outline:none; cursor:pointer; float:right;     border-padding:4px; border-right: 5px solid #ed2024; }

.hiddendiv{ display:none; width:300px; font-size: 2em; background-color:#ed2024; float:left; padding:5px; }

.clicker:focus + .hiddendiv{ display:block; }

.clicker:focus{ display:block; float:left;
 }

.hiddendiv a{   float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
}
```

I understand that focus doesn't let me click the link within the .hiddendiv element, but target doesn't seem to work either. I'd like to build this with css only. any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show/hide content via CSS, I would use a checkbox label to toggle state.

```css
.clicker {
  font-size: 4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddendiv, #checkbox {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + .hiddendiv {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <label class="clicker" tabindex="1" for="checkbox">clicker</label>
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <div class="hiddendiv"> <a href="/register/register">Register</a>
    <a href="/account/login">Login</a></div>
</nav>
```

But if you want to trigger it on `:target` you would do it like this

```css
.clicker {
  font-size: 4em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddendiv {
  display: none;
}

.hiddendiv:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="clicker" tabindex="1"><a href="#hiddendiv">menu</a></div>
  <div class="hiddendiv" id="hiddendiv"> <a href="/register/register">Register</a>
    <a href="/account/login">Login</a></div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!